# Why isn't my store method saving the form input to my database?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need some small help real quick, its about my store method in my ProductController@store. Basically I have a form createProduct.blade.php, that allows the user to add a product, name, image, description and a link. The ProductController@store then picks up the form input data and saves it inside the database. Now my problem is the data is not saved inside my database, and the view is not returned to /pr which is my productManagement.blade.php page and there is no error message displayed when running the code. The current output is just an empty form after clicking submit. I want the output to be the form input data stored into the database and the user redirected to /pr. I have included some code, that I think should be causing this major headache problem.

ProductController@store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
        $image              = $request->file('input_img');
        $name               = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath    = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $this->save();
    }
    $data = request()->validate([
        'productName'        => 'required',
        'productLink'        => 'required',
        'productPrice'       => 'required',
        'productDescription' => 'required',
    ]);
    $product = new Product([
        'productName'        => $request->get('productName'),
        'productLink'        => $request->get('productLink'),
        'productPrice'       => $request->get('productPrice'),
        'productDescription' => $request->get('productDescription')
    ]);
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/pr');
}
```

createProduct.blade.php

```
<form action="/storeProduct" method="post">
@csrf
  <label for="productName">Product Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productName') }}"><br>
  @error('productName') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productImage">Product Image:</label><br>
  <input type="file" id="productImage" name="productImage" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productImage') }}"><br>
  @error('productImage') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productLink">Product Link:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productLink" name="productLink" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productLink') }}"><br>
  @error('productLink') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productPrice">Product Price:</label><br>
  <input type="decimal" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productPrice') }}"><br>
  @error('productPrice') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productDescription">Product Description:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productDescription" name="productDescription" autocomplete="off" value=" 
   {{ old('productDescription') }}"><br>
      @error('productDescription') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> 
@enderror
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/storeProduct', 'ProductController@store');
```

So yeah, I don't know why this doesn't work.  I read the solution for storing an image from another stackoverflow question with 41 upvotes so idk why that solution works for everyone but me.... Thanks for reading and trying to help.

Comment: you should have another method in that controller called `save()`, can you add it to your question ?

Comment: you need to adjust your form to handle uploading the file `enctype='multipart/form-data'` ... also what is `input_img` you don't have any file input with that name ... only  `productImage`

Comment: Ah! I forgot to change input_img to productImage when learning from the other stackoverflow question....

Comment: I don't have a thing called save()... my controller is like a base resource controller, where it generates all the methods it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code on your views (createProduct.blade.php)

```
    <form action="/storeProduct" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Don't forget to call your database model (Product), located at the top of the controller (ProductController)

use App\Product;

if it doesn't work, please try changing the validation format.
(THIS WORKS FOR ME WITH A BLANK PAGE WITHOUT ERROR)

```
    $request->validate([
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
```